# Angular 2 Links To External URLs Treated As Relative Paths For Routing

Tags: javascript, angular, components, property-binding

I've created a component which receives properties set on it's selector:

```
<app-navigation-card
        label="My Label"
        description="Description of Item"
        type="download"
        [links]="[{path:'https://somedomain.com/somefile.zip', label:'Download'}]"
></app-navigation-card>
```

The inputs are set up in the NavigationCard class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation-card',
  templateUrl: './navigation-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation-card.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() label: String;
  @Input() description: String;
  @Input() links: Object;
  @Input() type: String;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In the template:

```
<div class="label">{{label}}</div>
<div class="description">{{description}}</div>
<ul *ngIf="links != undefined" class="links">
  <li *ngFor="let link of links" [routerLink]="link.path">
    <span *ngIf="type == 'download'"><a href="{{link.path}}">{{link.label}}</a></span>
    <span *ngIf="type == 'navigation'" [routerLink]="link.path"><{{link.label}}</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If type `== navigation`, the router redirects to the correct component, but when it's a download, I'm getting this error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'style-guide/https%3A/somedomain.com/somefile.zip'

This URL works fine when explicitly entered in the href of a link but not via property binding. Any idea how to remedy this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider creating an anchor tag as its seems to be an external URL which going to download a file. Rather remove `*ngIf` and just have 1st elements of `*ngFor` without `span` wrapper.

Additionally remove routerLink added to li element, which is getting fired the router.navigate function because of event bubbling.

```
<li *ngFor="let link of links">
    <a [attr.href]="link.path">{{link.label}}</a>
</li>
```

Or else have a `click` event & call function from controller, and open path in new tab using `window.open(path)`. It will automatically download the file.

Comment: From my understanding, this bypasses the whole purpose of internal routing (SPA) and is essentially a new hit to the website at said URL.

Comment: @ChrisWhite this is specific case where router should not be aware of this external URL navigation, since we used `href`..

Answer (score 0):

You can add `https://` before the variable.

```
<a [attr.href]="'https://' + link.path">{{link.label}}</a>
```

Angular will recognize this as an absolute path, and redirect you to the URL.